# Can TortoiseSVN 1.8 work with Apache SVN 1.6?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I followed the instructions here to install SVN in my Linux (2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64, Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4).

It installs svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486) by running `"yum install mod_dav_svn subversion"`.

Questions:

1. We want to use TortoiseSVN and SVN eclipse plugin as the client. Can we use the latest TortoiseSVN 1.8.3? How about eclipse plugin?
2. Can I upgrade the SVN in my Linux to the latest Apache SVN 1.8.3?

Comment: I'm assuming the Linux `SVN` is your server? There is a page somehwere on the site that gives specifics, but yes. Also they have download links: http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release

Comment: Yes, that Linux is our SVN server to host the repositories. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 1.x clients are compatible with all 1.x clients when you use Apache or svnserve to host the repository. When using mismatched versions, any features that are supported by one end but not the other will be disabled and fall back to the features that are compatible where applicable.

All clients that operate on a single working copy must have matching versions. So if you have both TortoiseSVN and an Eclipse plugin that you'll need to use with the same WC, you must match versions.

Comment: Technically, you must have major/minor version match to work on the same working copy (e.g. 1.7.3 and 1.7.1 would be ok, 1.7.3 and 1.8.2 would not).